# What is the meaning of Enter The Void?

Tags: analysis, enter-the-void

The movie Enter The Void (2009) directed by Gaspar Noé of France (born in Argentina) impressed me more than 99.99% I have ever watched. But now I'm wondering about its meaning and what it is representing.

What did the director want to show by all the over-watching, flickering of lights, and by the characters? It was pretty surreal, I love the surrealism, but I guess I missed something. That's what I want to know. Also, in a scene where a man was sitting near fire, he was being searched by the police, so he had to live on the street. He writes "I want to die" when the camera first moved to him while he was lighting the fire, but the next time when the camera moves to him, the text is changed to "I want to live."

[image: Oscar visiting a colorful toys shop in Japan with his sister]

Comment: I'm afraid this question might be a bit too broad to be answered reasonably. Could you pinpoint what you're looking for or what is unclear to you a bit more specifically?

Comment: Yes, I need to clarify the plot-explainaxtion. What did the director want to show by all the overwatching, flickering of lights, and by the characters? It was pretty surreal, I love the surrealism, but I guess I miss something. That's what I want to know. Also, in a scene where a man was sitting near fire, he was being searched by the police, so he had to live on the street. He write "I want to die" when the camera first moved to him while he was lighting the fire, but the next time when the camera, the text changed to "I want to live."

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add this information, not in the comments.

Comment: What do you mean, @Luciano ?

Comment: Exactly what you just did: always edit the question to add more info, don't add it in the comments. Check the [help] if you want to know more about the site.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for pinpointing. Actually, I'm new to Stackexchange and learning its norms. I like the scholarly way it organizes its contents.

Comment: Just be careful if you feel inspired to watch Irréversible--that's one you'll never be able to unsee!

Comment: I have already watched that phenomenal movie.